# Regarding conversion of Ghost blog to static pages and Prismjs

Tags: jekyll, ghost-blog

I have a Ghost blog. I would like to host it using Jekyll etc. using static pages that I would be generating.

I use Prismjs for syntax highlighting.
How is Jekyll going to handle this situation considering that static pages will have no Javascript support?
Do I need to make changes from my side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Static pages will have no JavaScript support.

Wrong. Static page doesn't have database support, but it supports JavaScript (quite obvious actually).

Jekyll has built-in syntax highlight engines with [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) or [Rouge](https://github.com/jayferd/rouge). Pygments needs Python, while Rouge is pure Ruby based. Please have a look at documentation [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code_snippet_highlighting).

If you don't want to use built-in engine, yes, Prism is also possible. You can totally follow the usual usage like [this](http://prismjs.com/), or use [this](https://github.com/gmurphey/jekyll-prism-plugin) Jekyll Prism Plugin. For example, [this article](http://yizeng.me/2014/02/23/how-to-get-window-size-resize-or-maximize-window-using-selenium-webdriver/) in my blog uses both built-in Pygments highlighting (for Ruby and Python code) and JavaScript Google prettify highlighting (for C# code).

If you don't know how to use JavaScript in your Jekyll project, please post your repository link, so we can help out.

Comment: I had some doubts on where Prismjs gets executed. I thought it gets executed server side and the HTML that the browser receives has the highlighting.

I am totally new to web technologies. With server-side and client-side Javascript all around a doubt crept in.

Thanks for clearing that doubt.